# schedule after 0:00 hour not working before first interval

Tags: mysql, time, intervals, schedule

I have a table with 4 schedule interval:

```
id  time_int    progr_comment   A   B   C   D
1   05:30:00    Good Morning    1   4   2   17
2   06:50:00    Have a nice day 1   4   2   17
3   17:00:00    Welcome Home    1   4   4   23
4   18:30:00    Good Evening    1   4   2   22
5   22:00:00    Good Night      1   4   2   20
```

For each interval I compare with `NOW()` and I will take the variables (A, B, C, D) from table based on `time_int <= NOW()` then my program create a query to mysql. The problem come after 0:00 hour. The query does not find anything until `NOW()` pass the first interval (ex. 5:30:00).

Comment: Please add the relevant query you use for selecting the data.

Comment: What would you want your query to return in such cases?

Comment: "SELECT * FROM `_LG_Program` WHERE `_LG_Program`.`time_int` <= NOW() AND `_LG_Program`.`A` = 1 AND `_LG_Program`.`B` = 4 ORDER BY `_LG_Program`.`time_int` DESC LIMIT 1"

Comment: I means I need to retrieve the parameters A B C D values that match my current time with the intervals. My problems is after 0:00, the 22:00:00 cannot be smaller than 0:00:00 its one day minus.